# Object Instantiation Rules with Subclasses

Tags: class, object, subclass

[image: Vehicles UML Class Diagram]I am a bit confused with knowing whether or not these are legal.
This is the code I have.

```
Vehicle milleniumFalcon = new PassengerVehicle();
FreightVehicle nautilus = new FreightVehicle();
PassengerVehicle deLorean = new PassengerVehicle();
```

I need to find out whether these are legal or not.

```
milleniumFalcon = new PassengerAirbus();
Vehicle gruMobile = new FreightPlane();
deLorean = new Vehicle();
nautilus = deLorean;
milleniumFalcon = new Vehicle();
```

My thoughts are that the first one is not legal because milleniumFalcon uses the type PassengerVehicle and we cannot have PassengerAirbus because it is not a subclass of PassengerVehicle.

For the second one I think no because FreightPlane is not a subclass of Vehicle.

For the third one I think yes because you are making a new Vehicle called deLorean.

For the fourth one I think no because you cannot have the FreightVehicle = Vehicle, because they are different classes.

For the last one I think no because we already have something called milleniumFalcon so would need to change the name for it work.

Not sure if this is right so any clarification if my reasoning is on the right track would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You wrote: _PassengerAirbus ... is not a subclass of PassengerVehicle_ But it is because its parent class (i.e. `PassengerPlane`) is a subclass of `PassengerVehicle`. In any case, can you not write the code for the classes? If something in the class hierarchy is not legal then you should get a compile-time error, i.e. the code will not compile. Is there a programming language associated with this exercise?

Comment: This model is problematic because the role that something plays can change (e.g., passenger to freight and back) and is not fundamental to what the thing is. I know this doesn’t answer your question, but it is important to learn.

Comment: @Abra even though it is a subclass it cannot be legal because once an object is created its type cannot be changed. This would be the same answer for the fifth one regardless of whether its a subclass or parent class or whatever?